# Javascript array inputing and display user defined data

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am a trying to write a program for my class that asks the users for a keyboard character and then for number of rows and columns, then displays the character in a rectangle shape based on the rows and columns.

```
var keyBoardInput = prompt("Pick a key on your keyboard to display");
var x = prompt("How many rows?");
var y = prompt("How many columns?");

rectangleX = new Array(x);
rectangleY = new Array(y);

for(var i =0; i < rectangleX.lenght; i++)
    {
    rectangleX.push(keyBoardInput);
    }

for(var j =0; j < rectangleY.lenght; j++)
   {
   rectangleY.push(keyBoardInput);
   }
```

I'm not sure how to get it to output so say if there was 3 rows and 2 columns and the user chose `a` as the keyboard input, I would need an output of something like:

```
aaa
aaa
```

Comment: how are you planning to output it?

Comment: document.write() has been the norm but im not sure how to get to display in the rectangle way like the AAAs in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be 2 rows and 3 columns, but if it´s just always the same letter, you can just make a double loop iterating your rows and columns, and set the corresponding text that you want to output:

```js
var x = 2
var y = 3


html = '';

for(var i =0; i < x; i++){ // for each row
    for(var j =0; j < y; j++){ // we add a 'a' for each column in the row
            html+= 'a'
    } 
    // we already made a row, now we need a new line for the next row to show in the next line
 html+='<br/>'
}


var newParagraph = document.createElement('p'); // we create a paragraph element
    newParagraph.innerHTML = html; // set the html we made
document.body.appendChild(newParagraph); // and add it to the dom
```

And with ecmascript6 we could use a one liner solution taking advantage of the string repeat function:

```
html = ('a'.repeat(y)+'<br/>').repeat(x)
```

Comment: The letter to be displayed as well as the rows(x) and columns(y) are all user defined.

Comment: @JoshuaWalters yeah, replace the 'a' with  your keyBoardInput  variable and prompt for x and y instead of fixed values, was just showing an example

Comment: ok thank you i for got a bracket and it wasnt running so i thought it was the variable change

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like that:

```
var output = "";

for(var i = 0; i <3; i++){
  for(var j = 0; j <3; j++){
    output +="A";
  }
  output+="<br>";
}

document.write(output);
```

The result will be:

```
AAA
AAA
AAA
```

Answer (score 0):

or other way with

```
alert(rectangleX + '\n' + rectangleY);
```

or

```
console.log(rectangleX + '\n' + rectangleY);
```

Comment: This won´t actually work with x = 10 and y = 10, for example

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x = 2
var y = 3


html = '';

for(var i =0; i < x; i++){ // for each row
    for(var j =0; j < y; j++){ // we add a 'a' for each column in the row
            html+= 'a'
    } 
    // we already made a row, now we need a new line for the next row to show in the next line
 html+='<br/>'
}


var newParagraph = document.createElement('p'); // we create a paragraph element
    newParagraph.innerHTML = html; // set the html we made
document.body.appendChild(newParagraph); // and add it to the dom
```

```js
var BR = "<br />";  // Line break
var ES = "";        // Empty space
var PA = "<p />";   // full paragraph break

// Program heading

// Get inputs
var keyBoardInput = prompt("Pick a key on your keyboard to display");
var x = prompt("How many rows?");
var y = prompt("How many columns?");
var html = "";

rectangleX = new Array(x);
rectangleY = new Array(y);

for(var i =0; i < x; i++)
 { // for each row
    for(var j =0; j < y; j++)
 { // we add a 'a' for each column in the row
            html+= keyBoardInput
    } 
    // we already made a row, now we need a new line for the next row to show in the next line
 html+='<br/>'
}
 


// do the maths, and display the results
var newParagraph = document.createElement('p'); // we create a paragraph element
    newParagraph.innerHTML = html; // set the html we made
document.body.appendChild(newParagraph); // and add it to the dom
// thank user and end the program
document.write(PA + "Thank you for using this program. Good-bye!");
```

Comment: Here is the final working program thank you for all who helped with it.